# Apache internal rewrite module for unique URLs?

Tags: oracle, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to create a secure download web app with the following scenario. Anybody know how this can be achieved:

1) The user is given a one-time URL
    a) This one-time URL is stored in an Oracle DB mapped to the actual URL
2) When the user visits the one-time URL:
    a) Apache module connects to the DB to see if the one-time URL exists
    b) if it exists, apache does an **internal** rewrite to the actual URL
    c) if not, then 404 or any sort of error (404 or something else) is good enough

2.a and 2.b are the what I am looking answers on. I am not sure how to do this and make sure the rewrites happen internally.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be possible using the new dbd-type RewriteMap functionality available in the trunk version of Apache. Obviously with this being the current development branch of the server you'll need to be careful about config-breaking changes over time.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap urlmapper "dbd:SELECT redirect_url from my_table WHERE some_key = %s"
RewriteRule /one_time/(.+) ${urlmapper:$1|/404.html}
```

Of course you will need some additional logic for handling cases where no results are returned.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/rewrite/rewritemap.html#dbd

Comment: Obviously being in the development branch you need to be careful full stop.

Comment: Sounds like this could work. This is production thing though so it might have to wait till apache 2.3 is released, which I believe is due any day now (hopefully). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible just by apache.  What you must want to do is:

- Configure apache to redirect that unique links to a server script which will make the "magic" happen
- the server script checks if the unique provided url is still valid and acts in accordance:

  - serves the file and invalidate (delete or mark as served) the unique-url row in database
  - replies with status 404 or redirects to a 404 page in other cases

The exact details on how to make things happen depends on the scripting engines available to you on the server, and your preferences.  It can be done in a variety of engines, from php to cgi to .NET to asp and many others.

Comment: Right, but server script would imply header redirect or streaming by data through service and I am trying to avoid that due to constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out... You can achieve this using XSEND (https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/)... Setup a php script to handle any URI's with file download and denied all access to the actual file directory so the only way to get the file it to force it through XSEND.